# A hard geometry problem for high school olympiad

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry

> We give the circle $\Gamma$ with center $O$ and radius $r$. Let $AB$ be a fixed diameter of $\Gamma$ and let $K$ be a fixed point of the segment $[AO]$. Let us call $t$ the tangent to $\Gamma$ in $A$. For each chord $CD$ (other than $AB$) of $\Gamma$ passing through $K$, let us call $P$ and $Q$ the points of intersection of lines $BC$ and $BD$ with $t$.

> Prove that the product $|AP|\cdot|AQ|$ remains constant when the $CD$ chord varies.

Well, i wanna solve the problem : i found that the points P,C,D,Q Lie on a circle

Comment: Hi! What is your question? and maybe can you show your attempts?

Comment: Well, i wanna solve the problem : i found that the points P,C,D,Q Lie on a circle

Answer (score 1):

[image]

The problem is designed to mislead people into using power of point calculation while the correct solution includes only triangle similarities.

$${AP\over AB}={AC\over BC}\implies AP={AB\times AC\over BC}$$

$${AQ\over AB}={AD\over BD}\implies AQ={AB\times AD\over BD}$$

$$AP\times AQ=AB^2\times{AC\times AD\over BC\times BD}$$ $$=AB^2\times({AC\over BD})\times({AD\over BC})$$ $$=AB^2\times({CK\over BK})\times({AK\over CK})$$ $$=AB^2\times({AK\over BK})$$